# Adding different row values for Birt

Tags: birt

I got this selection of data from my sql:

[image]

I would like to add Cancelled, Disputed and Resolved together and then divide the result with the total shipped. All of this should be done with an Expression.

So x / 303 where x is the sum of the desired values.

Goal would be to get a % where I can tell how good my shipping is.
I would then like to display the result in a text label next to a graph. 
How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use computed columns in your data set:

Add a `SUM` on the column `Total` and a filter only matching the rows based on the column `Status` you want to select. The expression should look like:

```
if (row["Status"] == "Cancelled" || row["Status"] == "Disputed" 
 || row["Status"] == "Resolved")
  true 
else
  false
```

[image: Computed Columns]

create a second computed column only containing the "Total" value where the Status is Shipped.

```
if (row["Status"] == "Shipped")
  row["Total"]
```

Then create a third computed column where you divide both computed values and you are done.

```
row["sum"] / row["shipped"]
```

[image: shipped computed column]

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

create a new parameter and [refer the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lzj61.png)

create new static values and allow multiple values to be selected.
So, accordingly edit your SQL queries